# TypeError: Cannot read property 'expires' of undefined at MongoStore.Store.createSession

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, cookies

I'm building a webapp with Node.Js and React.Js, and I'm trying to use cookies, but this is very new to me and I'm just trying to figure out what to do. But for some reason I get this error when the server starts, or when I send two POST requests.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'expires' of undefined at MongoStore.Store.createSession (A:\Kiwi\server\node_modules\express-session\session\store.js:87:29)  
    at inflate (A:\Kiwi\server\node_modules\express-session\index.js:368:13)
    at A:\Kiwi\server\node_modules\express-session\index.js:495:11
    at A:\Kiwi\server\node_modules\connect-mongo\src\index.js:10:25
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
```

```
const express = require('express');
const session = require("express-session");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const MongoDBStore = require('connect-mongo')(session);
mongoose.connect("mongodb+srv://....@cluster0.zbjk9.mongodb.net/kiwi", { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true });

const store = new MongoDBStore({
  url: "mongodb+srv://....@cluster0.zbjk9.mongodb.net/kiwi",
  collection: 'sessions',
  stringify: false
});

app.use(session({
  secret: 'azta mindensegit mekkora titok',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  store: store,
  unset: 'keep',
  name: 'inCart',
  expires: new Date(Date.now() + (30 * 86400 * 1000))
}))

app.post("/cartadd", (req, res) => {
  const cartID = req.body.cartID;
  req.session.inCart = cartID;
  store.set(req.sessionID, req.session.inCart, (err) => {
    if (err) console.log(err);
  })
  res.send({ sessionID: req.sessionID })
})
```

If I delete all cookies in the browser and restart everything, after two POST requests, the server stops with the error mentioned above.

---

UPDATE ----
The problem was because of this part of the code:

```
app.post("/cartadd", (req, res) => {
      const cartID = req.body.cartID;
      req.session.inCart = cartID;
      store.set(req.sessionID, req.session.inCart, (err) => {
        if (err) console.log(err);
      })
      res.send({ sessionID: req.sessionID })
    })
```

I don't totally understand why, but you shouldn't set so many times a session.

Comment: What change to your code did you make to fix this? From what I can see the section you pasted in the Update was just a clip from the original code to show us where the issue was.